# Why am I getting this error on my local database and not on my live database?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, configuration, indexing, full-text-search

when I am querying the local database instead of live database I get the following error:

> Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT
>   predicate on table or indexed view
>   'Shop' because it is not full-text
>   indexed.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Next time, please post a complete question, not just a long title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means pretty much what it says; Full-text indexing isn't turns on for your Shop table.  Full-text indexing allows all the text within a field to be searched while querying, which is what I assume you want to do.

You probably have full-text indexing turned **off** on your development system, but on on your live server.

Please [read this page](http://www.developer.com/db/article.php/3446891) which explains how to enable it.